# why does a div where the height is not specified flood the whole height of the body?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have a div with a background color where the height is not specified so it makes sense for the background to cover the content of the div. When a second div exceeds this height the background color of the first div floods till the bottom of the content of the second div. Why is that?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/973q0d2j/)

html

```
<div class="first">test<div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

css

```
.first{
width: 30px;
background: red;
}
.second{
margin-left: 50px;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo: your first `<div>` isn't closed. End your first line with `</div>` and your fiddle works as expected.